# How to split text when read from file to Listview c++?

Tags: listview, c++-cli

This code shows all text in first column of ListView, but I need to split it by columns. I tried to write Split('|') after ReadLine() but it gives an error.

```
    String^ textFile = String::Concat("C:\\p.txt");
    StreamReader^ reader = gcnew  StreamReader(textFile);
    do
    {
        listView1->Items->Add(reader->ReadLine());

    } while (reader->Peek() != -1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the sub items separately. So you also need to split the string ahead of adding it...

```
String^ stitems[] = reader->ReadLine()->Split('|');

ListViewItem^ item1 = gcnew ListViewItem( "item1",0 );
for each (String^ x in stitems) item1->SubItems->Add(x);
```

There's a good c++/cli example here... [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)